# What is this high-wing single-engine plane performing a short landing?

Tags: aircraft-identification, single-engine, stol

[image]

Source: *Shortest Landing!!! Severe Headwind! Aircraft hovers and vertically touches down!* ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vP13XPMNfc))

What is this high-wing single-engine plane performing a short landing?

Comment: looks like a Piper Cub or one of its million derivatives. Picture doesn't show enough detail to be much more precise.

Comment: It looks more like a PA-18 super cub than a J-3 cub to me because it's slightly beefier, but it's very hard to tell the difference from that angle.

Comment: A J-3 has the front windshield struts intersect at the top at center in an inverted V. The Supercub is the other way around.  That's a Supercub.

Comment: Much more detail is visible in this animated gif of it apparently taking off backwards in a strong headwind. (Sorry, stack.imgur.com can't understand this image format.) https://cs9.pikabu.ru/images/big_size_comm_an/2017-06_2/1496817602161265640.gif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The video description (thanks to ymb1 for adding the link) says:

> By Jon Bush.

If you search for that name and STOL, you will find [his YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrEI7dTat1ZIxvx-Tc5xDPQ/featured), where you can find a higher quality video of that landing:

[image: SQ12 Landing]
<sup>([Ultimate Alaskan Plane Landing, Zero Feet!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJJI3kPZ0-I))</sup>

The video description says:

> Having too much fun flying this Experimental Stol Quest SQ12 supercub  in the wind on the Knik River in Alaska @akbushpilot.

So the aircraft is an **STOL Quest SQ12 Super Cub**, an experimental plane based on the design of the [Piper PA-18 Super Cub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_PA-18_Super_Cub).

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

This is a Piper Cub which has been modified with a high-performance propeller and tundra tires. It probably also has either a 150 or 180 HP engine in it.